# How to archive big Azure managed disk to storage account as VHD file

Tags: azure-blob-storage, archive, vhd, azure-disk, azure-managed-disk

We have Azure VMs that we don't need anymore. But, we want to archive the data and os disks to low cost archive storage.

I used the script given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-powershell-sample-copy-managed-disks-vhd

```
#Provide the subscription Id of the subscription where managed disk is created
$subscriptionId = "yourSubscriptionId"

#Provide the name of your resource group where managed is created
$resourceGroupName ="yourResourceGroupName"

#Provide the managed disk name 
$diskName = "yourDiskName"

#Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds e.g. 3600.
#Know more about SAS here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Az.Storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
$sasExpiryDuration = "3600"

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the underlying VHD of the managed disk. 
$storageAccountName = "yourstorageaccountName"

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded VHD will be stored
$storageContainerName = "yourstoragecontainername"

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy the VHD of the managed disk. 
$storageAccountKey = 'yourStorageAccountKey'

#Provide the name of the destination VHD file to which the VHD of the managed disk will be copied.
$destinationVHDFileName = "yourvhdfilename"

#Set the value to 1 to use AzCopy tool to download the data. This is the recommended option for faster copy.
#Download AzCopy v10 from the link here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10
#Ensure that AzCopy is downloaded in the same folder as this file
#If you set the value to 0 then Start-AzStorageBlobCopy will be used. Azure storage will asynchronously copy the data. 
$useAzCopy = 1 

# Set the context to the subscription Id where managed disk is created
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

#Generate the SAS for the managed disk 
$sas = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName -DurationInSecond $sasExpiryDuration -Access Read 

#Create the context of the storage account where the underlying VHD of the managed disk will be copied
$destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

#Copy the VHD of the managed disk to the storage account
if($useAzCopy -eq 1)
{
    $containerSASURI = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Context $destinationContext -ExpiryTime(get-date).AddSeconds($sasExpiryDuration) -FullUri -Name $storageContainerName -Permission rw
    azcopy copy $sas.AccessSAS $containerSASURI

}else{

    Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName
}
```

We have managed to copy VHD of the managed disk to a storage account. But, when it comes to copying the big disks up to 8 TB, the script fails with the following error

```
Response Details: <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format. </Message><HeaderName>x-ms-blob-content-length</HeaderName><HeaderValue>8796093022720</HeaderValue>
```

But, I see that Page blobs have a maximum size of 8TB and Block blobs have a maximum size of 4.75TB. Hence, copying disks larger than 4.75 doesn't look practical.

Is there any alternative way to archive very big data disks into archive storage?

- tried to reduce the size of the disk, but is still big.